# Read public posts from "own" Facebook page's timeline - Pages API requires review and business verification

Tags: facebook

For a recent PHP web project, I would like to import facebook posts from the customer's own facebook page to another web application. I planned to do this using a simple Graph query like:

```
GET /v3.0/{$pageId}/posts?fields=name,description,status_type,attachments{description,subattachments}
```

Unfortunately, due to the data leaks recently (March 2018) discussed in public media, Facebook has [severely limited access to its Pages API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review). I get the response:

> Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException: (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

Facebook now requires a **review** of the web application and a **business verification** for the use of the Pages API, at least until August 2018.

- Is there any other API that can be used for this simple usecase without those steps? I have access to Facebook accounts managing the one and only page I want to access.
- If you have any idea about the effort needed for review and business verification, I'd be grateful too. Also, I cannot disclose the app's source code, but it looks like this is not necessary?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS: _“While testing and before submitting for review, your app may only access content that is available on a Page that you own. If you want to access public content on other Pages, you must submit this feature for review.”_ - sounds to me as if having the page owner create the app id might be a simple solution here.

Comment: It appears this is a known issue: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/573130356406496/

Comment: I'm just now stuggling with this. you'd think it would be easier to get posts using your own account, from a page you administer. how did it work out for you?

Comment: @TiagoDuarte I had to tell my customer I was unable to implement that feature with reasonable effort. After all they were only willing to pay for a few hours and not days of work.

Answer (score 4):

From what I understand of your requirements, you could call this endpoint in stead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/page/feed

This would not require the Page Public Content Access permission; but it may have to pass a review, if you plan to scale up the amount of users.

The review process consists in you describing your intents, uploading a screencast and, possibly (not necessarily), prove the existence of your business.

**Edit**:
If you don't plan on scaling the amount of users, try and putting your app in **dev** mode (the opposite of **Live**) - it's a switch in the upper right corner of the page. The app will be accessible to you as if it had been published - so no review process, no proof of existence of a company.

Comment: Are you sure that adding yourself as a test user works without having to go through review? I've tried this with a page that I own myself, and I still get: "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook."

Comment: You can no longer add yourself as a test user it would seem. The only way is to go through the review process, which seems like overkill when your trying to get public posts, from a public page, that you own and administer.

Comment: Thanks for your input and sorry for the slow reply. I was not able to add myself as a test user. Using `feed` instead of `posts`, I still get the very same error message. This also means that the docs on these endpoints are wrong in stating that "any" access token token can get publicly shared posts (I used the ones generated using the page administrator user). I also did not find any permission named "Page public content access" in the facebook docs, so either it is new or it is rather some kind of feature than a permission.

Comment: Looks like it might have changed in such a way that you have to be an administrator in stead - if you go under Roles, make sure that your user is in there. If it is, just applying for the scopes they mention (submitting a review) should be enough - there should be no need for them to return with an answer, as long as you are an admin and you're using your own token. This works on my end - let me know.

Comment: Also, view my edit in the reply wrt. putting the app in dev mode.

Comment: I have the same problem with an app that is in development, if my access_token={{appId}}| {{appSecret}}, I have my app in review, I really hope it won't take so much longer, as I am waiting for 10 days already!

Comment: @choli my review took 40 days, and they came back with a decline! They said I don't have a good enough screencast. But there's nothing much I can cast, since it's just only to display my own page feed's pictures under my website.

Comment: haha, great, for me the same, this morning I got my decline. will see what i can do

Comment: @ZoM same here. Don't know what to do